# Restricting views using meteor-roles and iron-meteor works only in certain conditions

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, roles

All of this is from the `routes.js` file...

First, just three routes for a `new` operation and then two views that list those items differently depending on role; one for `director` and one for `actor`.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Routes

Router.route('/:_id/new_audition', {
  name: 'newAudition',
  controller: 'NewAuditionController',
  action: 'new',
  where: 'client'
});

Router.route('/:_id/feed', {
  name: ':UserFeed',
  controller: 'FeedController',
  action: 'view',
  where: 'client'
});

Router.route('/:_id/list_auditions', {
  name: 'listAuditions',
  controller: 'ListAuditionsController',
  action: 'view',
  where: 'client'
});
```

Then I'm just defining onBeforeAction behaviours so that `actors` users can view the `list_auditions` view and directors have access to the other two.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Functions for use with Router Hooks

var forDirectorsOnly = function() {
  if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'director')) {
    toastr.error("Only directors can view that page", "Invalid Permissions");
    Router.go("myProfile");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Director trying to view a page");
    this.next();
  }
};

var forActorsOnly = function() {
  if(!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'actor')) {
    toastr.error("Only actors can view that page", "Invalid Permissions");
    Router.go("myProfile");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Actor trying to view a page");
    this.next();
  }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// onBeforeAction Declarations

Router.onBeforeAction(forDirectorsOnly, {only: ['UserFeed', 'newAudition']});
Router.onBeforeAction(forActorsOnly, {only: ['listAuditions']});
```

#### This is what's happening:

- I'll sign in as a director and go to the `UserFeed` route and it displays just fine. (the `console.log` message doesn't display though.)
- I then go to the `newAudition` route and it redirects and displays a permissions error.
- The weird thing is that when I press `Back` in my browser, it displays the `newAudition` view correctly (and the `console.log` message also displays.)
- Finally, going to the `listAuditions` view correctly denies me permissions and even trying to go `Back` via browser continues to deny me access.

I'm at my wits end with this, I've looked at every possible question about this and tried reading the iron router documentation and meteor-roles documentation to see what was happening but I can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Router.go(routeName)` in your `onBeforeAction` hooks use `this.render(routeName)`. I'm not sure why exactly this is the case but using `Router.go()` inside a `onBeforeAction` results in the kinds of behaviors you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of restricting the access to the routes and redirecting, you could try something like the following the template:

```
<template name="newAudition">
    {{#isInRole "director"}}
        You cannot view this page. Go to Profile.
    {{/if}}
    {{#isInRole "actor"}}
        How the New Audition Content
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Also, show/hide your navigation links based on the user role.